# How to handle RecyclerView items of different sizes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a recyclerView with an adapter inflated inside a cardview. Each item in my list has a different size, because of different image sizes. I am facing visibility problem as cards get recycled, in my cardviews as shown:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

[EDIT] My CardView layout: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zdM5H54CtfxZBxk6x72uYnSbCzxCnT-_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: what is your cardview height?

Comment: set card view height as wrap_content or limit image size via weights

Comment: Its wrap_content already. You can see my complete cardview layout here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zdM5H54CtfxZBxk6x72uYnSbCzxCnT-_/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

In your `<ImageView>` you need to add `scaletype` property for it. Add it like below

```
<ImageView
 .......
android:scaleType="CENTER_INSIDE" >
```

It will change the ratio of your image but full image is visible. `fitxy` also visible whole image as well. Choose more suitable one according to your needs

You can see a good example here. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide find out what scale y=type you want and add it.

Comment: I have previously tried this. It only reduces the image size to the center, doesn't solve the visibility problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Lucifer said:

> In your  you need to add scaletype property for it

If you don't like center inside you can use `CENTER_CROP` or try anyone of the options.